# Identifying this bare mobile phone board

Tags: hardware, mediatek

I got hold of this bare mobile phone board (didn’t come with the original cover, so no real way to confirm, only knowing it’s non-Western manufactured). Just needing to identify the model.

I’m attaching a snapshot of the backside:

[image: Printed Circuit Board]

Notice the K107TOZCG V8.7 (A9) & B20210625 M32 serial.

Doing a search on these serial numbers didn’t turn up anything (these agencies, huh?). Only confirming that the hardware is meant to conform to Android 9, which the board came preinstalled with, & it is an ARM32 (confirmed by it *apparently* being equipped with 4GB — to be confirmed still); as I booted the board already.

The approximate dimensions are 6.5mm x 11.5mm.

EDIT:
I actually meant, 6.5cm x 11.5cm — centimeters. I meant the BOARD. Stupid, glitchy brain enabling even stupider people. No need to rig the search results to show those dimensions of the chips. Like I’ll desolder these chips to be re-used. Just buy any embedded device & you’ll get just as good capacities.

Comment: You do know that by flashing a modified Android kernel, you can spoof the hardware information & the apps would have but no idea, right?

Comment: Although, true, I can just boot to another Android image via fastboot, but why all the hassle when I can identify by simply looking at the hardware?

Comment: You wanna bet it’s a MTK6592? I’m fighting off the urge to cutoff the heat spreaders (don’t have an expensive rework station yet).

Comment: Why would the eMMC chip  (NAND flash) be a more important indicator than the SoC? Oh, I’ll take them both heat spreaders off if it calls for it. I’m just being careful for the moment. **(comment edited by moderator)**

Comment: origin of mainboard could be [karbonn](http://www.karbonnmobiles.com) mobile too (the tag you removed) and there is eMMC 16/32 GB version available

Answer (score 0):

[manufacturer](https://www.jlinksz.com/en/products/ten-inch.html): **JLinksz K960 Tablet**
mainboard version: k107-mb-8.7
mainboard date: 2020 09 01

- MediaTek MT6580A Quad Core SoC
- SK Hynix H26M52208FPR 16GB eMMC*
- Kernel 3.18.35+ (= Android 7 Nougat)

**eMMC manufacturer may vary on mainboard version*

[image]

source: [chinaphonearena.com](https://www.chinaphonearena.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=17681&pid=78061#pid78061)